# How to convert 1D tensor into a scalar value inside the graph?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I need to convert 1d tensor of shape (1,) into scalar 1 or () in tensorflow to use in tf.cond.

But the problem is in `tf.cond(number <T,treu_fn=..,false_fn=..` number is of shape (1,) and T is () just a scalar.

Sample code snippet:

```
number = tf.gather_nd(number_buffer,indices)
number = tf.cast(number,dtype=tf.int32)  #T is const of type int32
result = tf.cond(number < T,lambda: tf.add(i,1),lambda: tf.add(P,0))
```

When I run the session, I am getting below error.

```
ValueError: Shape must be rank 0 but is rank 1 for '{{node while/cond/Switch}} = Switch[T=DT_BOOL](while/Less_1, while/Less_1)' with input shapes: [1], [1].
```

I know the reason, but I do not know how to fix this error.

one can consider it as reducing the rank of a tensor as well.

Could someone help me with this!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `number` tensor is of shape `(1,)`, which you can just [`squeeze`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/squeeze) or [`reshape`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reshape) to make it a scalar:

```py
number = tf.squeeze(number)
```

Make sure the `tf.gather_nd` returns only one element, meaning `indices` must be an array of length 1.